# Как делать аргументы в несколько слов в discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

У меня есть следующий отрывок кода:

```
@Bot.command
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def repban(usr, time, rule):
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при сообщении
!repban person 12h rule 17
У переменных usr, time и rule были значения, при условии, что кавычки не надо использовать

```
usr = "person"
time = "12h"
rule = "rule 17"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже сам нашёл ответ в документации. Для этого нужно перед параметром поставить *, например:

```
@Bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def banrep(ctx, usr, time, *, rule):
    usr = str(usr)
    time = str(time)
    rule = str(rule)
    Emb = discord.Embed(title=f"Выдан бан игроку " + usr, colour = discord.Color.purple())
    Emb.add_field(name="Срок", value=time, inline=True)
    Emb.add_field(name="По причине", value=rule, inline=True)
    ban_message = await ctx.send(embed=Emb)
    print("Issued ban report. Report arguments: " + usr + time + rule)
    ban_message_id = ban_message.id
```

В результате мы получаем вот это:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Могу вам посоветовать присваивать тип переменной в параметрах: `async def banrep(ctx, usr: str, time: str, *, rule: str):` вместо этого: `usr = str(usr) time = str(time) rule = str(rule)`, чтобы избежать нагромождение кода

Comment: Спасибо за совет!